# Register varibles in Verilog by using Quartus and FPGA

Tags: cpu, verilog, fpga, cpu-registers, quartus

I wonder, how is process behind when we use reg variable in verilog. We know that, in Quartus using by any FPGA we can declare and handle many registers. Also, we know that recent-i7(64 bit) CPUs have just 16 register. When we compile and simulate our code that has more than for example 50 register, it works. These registers are stored in any memory block? If so, why do we define this variable as reg? I mean when we define variable as reg in verilog registers should(am I wrong?) be handled in CPU registers but CPU has no more than 16 register. I am confused.

Comment: `recent-i7(64 bit) CPUs` and the register/memory blocks of an FPGA are completely different. [See this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-among-CPU-GPU-APU-FPGA-DSP-and-Intel-MIC)

Comment: This question is probably too vague for SO, but heres a few clarifying points that might help. First, its important to understand that while `reg` type variables in Verilog typically map to hardware registers, this is not always the case, they might map to memory cells or might be optimized out by the synthesis tool (Quartus' in this case). Second, an i7 has way more than 16 registers in the total design, you are just thinking of the general purpose registers exposed to the programmer. To actually fully implement an x86 core, you have many many more registers in the design.

Comment: Thirdly, the number of registers reported by Quartus is the total number of hardware registers needed to implement your design. Register here can be thought of as groups of DFFs that are needed to implement the design. Im not 100% sure where the number comes from though. Note also that register in the CS sense from a programmer point of view is NOT the same as `reg` or register used in Verilog design. While the CS register is a hardware registers, any design will probalby used at least an order of magnitude more registers in the implementation as they expose to the programmer.

Comment: @Unn has described the points perfectly. Here is a link to help visualize what the synthesizer does to some registers and nets. [Registers and Nets in Verilog](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/wire_reg.html)

Comment: Where are the answers that explains difference between FPGAs and CPUs? I would read them. Someone removed good answers thank you cruel admins.

Comment: I think our purpose should be to build bridge, not destroy bridges, Better world you will have I am sure

Answer (score 0):

> These registers are stored in any memory block?

No. Without spacial implementation Quartus tool use registers from logic cells.

Some ALTERA device have UFM (User flash memory). You can use it to hold data:

https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/an/an489.pdf

https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_alt_ufm.pdf

Sorry for My English.